# Rails 5—Assets not loading in production (url not being found)

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

On my local machine, I have a play button that shows this in the inspector:

```
background-image: url(/assets/play-icon-ee4bd1dd973b8a19ce1ff95cc5ee63e393ea65b86b28d29d0cf7ac8dec98951b.svg);
```

But in production it can't find the asset and the inspector shows this:

```
background-image: url(play-icon.svg);
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please try
`background: image-url("play-icon.svg")`

then run `rake assets:precompile`